# Dynamically check each series in dataframe for phrase and remove

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

Suppose I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
                _id                       name                  features
0               574                      Test1          Reference:5dft55
1                57                      Test2           Reference:5sh85
2                52                      Test3                       675
```

Is it possible to ***dynamically*** search each series within the dataframe and check whether a series contains the word `Reference:` and if it does it should remove that so that the output can look like the dataframe below:

**Expected Ouput:**

```
                _id                       name                  features
0               574                      Test1                    5dft55
1                57                      Test2                     5sh85
2                52                      Test3                       675
```

Comment: Use  `df['url'] = df['url'].replace({'Reference:': ''}, regex=True)`

Comment: My question is a similar topic but completely different, I'm going for a dynamic approach, the other post is static which means they can explicitly specify the column name. I cannot specify the column name so it needs to manually check the dataframe whether that phrase is contained anywhere

Comment: `df['url']`  - you are explicitly specifying a column name, something that is dynamic means you cannot just type a column name, the code has to manually find the column which has the word `reference:` in it and then get the substring of it

Comment: So if use `df = df.replace({'Reference:': ''}, regex=True)` working well ?

Comment: A being the DF name ..you may try .. A = A.apply(lambda y:y if y.dtype=='int' or y.dtype=='float' else y.apply(lambda x:x if 'Reference' not in x else x.split("Reference:")[-1]))

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @Amit df.replace doesn't do partial matches so if it's not how the string is actually specified in the replace it wont do anything, I need to check if the column contains that word, and if it does then replace it